# 100 % height not working on all of the divs

Tags: html, css, height

I'm trying to get the 100 % height work but at some point the text flows over the divs. (Site url: http://uusilegenda.net/)

Here is the wrapper css:

`#wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #666;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    border-left: 2px solid #666;
    border-right: 2px solid #666;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;`

And here is the css of the menu bar:

`#content2 {
    float: left;
    left:0;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
    border-right: 1px solid #666;`

If I add

```
 clear: both; 
 overflow:hidden;
```

to the wrapper div and remove

```
position: absolute;
```

from the content div it almost looks like right but then the menu bar isn't full height.

And before you say that the css is poor, don't blame me, it is my friend's layout/css. :)

Comment: post the relevant code in question instead of posting website links.

Comment: include your error'ed markup here. As the question will be worthless once you've fixed the issue

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here and the css code is my friend's so I'm not quite sure where the error would be. I'll be wiser next time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute` from `#content2`

and changed the `width` of `#content1main`

but ultimately you should rethink your whole css as your's is quite bad.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the 1st answer about your css/layout needing to be re-written in a better way, but a quick fix would be this:

**Add** the following css to the existing style rules:

```
#wrapper { clear: both; overflow:hidden; }

#content1main { width: 760px; }
```

**Remove** the following css on the existing style rule:

```
#content2 { position: absolute }
```

These will fix your layout issues.

Comment: I fixed the first post. With these changes the layout isn't still looking as it should look.